# ASP.NET MVC - Ajax.BeginForm - conditionally pop-up modal dialog upon form submit?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I have a voting control that has several buttons. It is implemented using `Ajax.BeginForm` that has a hidden field named `voteTypeHidden`. Any time any of the voting buttons is clicked, it changes the value of voteTypeHidden, to update what type of vote is being cast. This form is submitted to the server, and it reports back with any error using `ViewState["VoteError"`].  Now, I want to display this error using my javascript function

```
ModalDialog(button, text, fadeOut)
```

How to accomplish this? **It is very important that the text parameter passed to the ModalDialog function is ViewState["VoteError"].**

Btw, it is not necessary, but I have also posted the code that I am using.

Here is the javascript:

```
    <script  type = "text/javascript">
    var voteClickEnabled = true; 
    function voteClicked_Set(value) {
        var voteType = value;
        document.getElementById("voteTypeHidden").setAttribute("value", value); 
    }
    function voteBegin() {
        //alert("begin"); 
        if (voteClickEnabled == false) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            voteClickEnabled = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    function voteEnd() {
        //alert("end"); 
        voteClickEnabled = true;
    }

</script>
```

Here is the view:

```
<div id  = "updateVotes">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>


Favorite : 
    <%=Html.Encode(ViewData["FavoriteCount"]) %>

<%//if(((int)ViewData["VoteBits"] & 1) == 0) 
{%>
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Voting", "Vote", new {voted = ViewData["voted"], favorited = ViewData["favorited"], markedspam = ViewData["markedspam"],  VotingOnId = (long)ViewData["VotingOnId"], VoteOn = (int)ViewData["VoteOn"], num_votes = 0, num_favorite = (int?)ViewData["FavoriteCount"], sdg = (int?)ViewData["sdg"], category = (int?)ViewData["category"] }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updateVotes", OnBegin = "voteBegin", OnComplete = "voteEnd"  }))
       {%>
        <%=Html.Hidden("voteTypeHidden", "temp", new { id = "voteTypeHidden" })%>
        <%if ((bool)ViewData["voted"] == false)
          { %>
        <%=Html.SubmitImage("voteButton", Url.Content("/Images/thumb_up.png"), new {value = "1", onclick = "voteClicked_Set(this.value)" })%>
        <%}
          else
          { %>
        <%=Html.SubmitImage("voteButton", Url.Content("/Images/cancel.png"), new { value = "2", onclick = "voteClicked_Set(this.value)" })%>
        <%} %>
         <%if ((bool)ViewData["favorited"] == false)
           { %>
        <%=Html.SubmitImage("voteButton", Url.Content("/Images/star_off_32.png"), new { value = "3", onclick = "voteClicked_Set(this.value)" })%>
         <%}
           else
           { %>
        <%=Html.SubmitImage("voteButton", Url.Content("/Images/star_32.png"), new { value = "4", onclick = "voteClicked_Set(this.value)" })%>
         <%} %>
         <%if ((bool)ViewData["markedspam"] == false)
           { %>
        <%=Html.SubmitImage("voteButton", Url.Content("/Images/error.png"), new { value = "5", onclick = "voteClicked_Set(this.value)" })%>
        <%}
           else
           { %>
        <%=Html.SubmitImage("voteButton", Url.Content("/Images/error_go.png"), new { value = "6", onclick = "voteClicked_Set(this.value)" })%>
        <%} %>
    <%}%>
<%}%>
<div id = "testingAjax">
</div>

<% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ViewData["VoteError"])) { %>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    ModalDialog("testingAjax", "asd", false);
</script>
<%} %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do normal html button image all with same class but you a html attribute of say  data-votetype=""

place a hidden div at top of page called results or feedback or something like that, based on the idea that the button class is vote:

```
$('.vote').live("click",function(e){
    var voteType = $(this).attr("data-votetype");
    // do post to JsonResults
    $.ajax(
     url: "",
     type:"POST",
     data:{id:$("#idfield").val(),votetype:voteType},
     dataType:"json",
     success: function(data){
        $("#feedback").html(data.Message).show(); 

     },
     error:function(a,b,c){ $("#feedback").html("Error description: " + b).show(); }
    );
});
```

if your going to work with ajax, you may as well work with the the data model its designed for and that's a JSON respone, example code:

```
public class JsonResponseModel {
      public bool Success {get;set;}
      public string Message {get;set;}
}

public JsonResults CastVote(int id, int votetype){
      var model =  new JsonREsponseModel{ Success = false };
      // do code in try catch. change model to reflect success and message
      return Json(model);
}
```